# Function iMA is returning different return value from expected (MQL5)

Tags: moving-average, mql5, forex

I'm using MQL5 (my first code). 
I want to use a script that uses MA, but first, I wanted to confirm the value to verify I'm doing correctly. Using a very basic code into script:

```
 double x=0;
 x = iMA(Symbol(),Period(),100,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE);
 Alert("The actual MA from last 100 points of EURUSD actually is: " + x;
```

The expected value is near the actual price... 1.23456, but this function is returning 10.00000 or 11.0000. 
I believe I'm missing something, and https://www.mql5.com/es/docs/indicators/ima helplink is not quite clear enough.

I already saw another similar function: `MA[0]` which seems to bring the moving average from specific candle, but, I don't know how to manage the Period range (100) or if is related to Close/Open variables on it. I didn't find any specific helplink to review.

Any ideas are very appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

x should be `int`, it is a handler of the MA. So each indicator when created in MT5 receives its handler, and you can use it later to get what you need. If you need several MA's - create several handlers and give each of them different names (x1, x2 or add some sense). Expert advisors in the default build of MT5 are good examples on what to do.

Comment: if you need examples here - please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
My next question should be "what is a handler" but i believe you gave me a good keyword to investigate. Thank you!!

Comment: When you open, for example, a file, or open/create another object, lets say MA object (with its period and other params) - you can try to get this object again (by opening a file again, or by computing MA from the very beginning) but definitely that is not optimal, saving a reference to the object (and using it, and not confusing with other objects that is crutial) is faster. This of that as a reference stored in Integer value.

Comment: I think you should put how should I use that or put refrences in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The iMA function Returns the handle of a specified technical indicator, not the "moving average" value.

For example, to get the value of the Moving average you can use this (in MQ4):

```
 EMA34Handler = iMA(NULL,0,34,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE);

 EMA34Value = CopyBuffer(EMA34Handler, 0,0);
```